# How to share common code among the Azure functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have common code which is require in other Azure functions, how can I share the common code among the Azure functions?

Comment: What language are you working with? If this is C#, this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540951/azure-functions-shared-classes/39541156#39541156

Comment: C#, Thanks I will try with this link

Comment: How can I add nuget references for shared code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Functions you are wanting to share code between are under the same Function App you can do the following:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39541156/2854993

And if they are separate Function Apps, I asked a similar question - see:

[Azure Functions - Shared code across Function Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982972/azure-functions-shared-code-across-function-apps/43983391#43983391)

Comment: @furqanms https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#using-nuget-packages

Comment: But my share code is outside of azure functions and it is inside wwwroot/shared/common.csx folder, so how can I give reference s into this share files and where the package will be defined for this share code in general?

Comment: @furqanms sorry I see what you mean. When I have done it previously, I have put the nuget dependencies in all of the project.json files of the functions which use the code in wwwroot/shared/common.csx - not sure if this is the correct approach but it seemed to work.

Comment: I am not sure is it work or not , looking for good approach  , because I am working on enterprise application and need to implement it perfect and clear. Adding nuget to each functions is not good approach for me

Comment: @furqanms perhaps post a new question or update this one. I would be interested to know the proper answer myself.

Comment: @furqanms ask it here in a comment? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411536/how-can-i-use-nuget-packages-in-my-azure-functions

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get shared code to work (or rather: compile) using an [Azure Function Tools for Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/12/01/visual-studio-tools-for-azure-functions/) project. In case of the screenshot, the shared library is actualy another Function project. I also tried to work with class libraries: those seem to work as well.

Haven't gotten around to deploying it yet, by the way. Running (and debugging) it localy is not an issue, so I guess deploying shouldn't be one either.

[image: Shared library]